# Using sh -c if comparisons inside an SSH command

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement, ssh

I'm having some trouble with the != section of the if statement. Essentially this statement is valid as far as I'm aware, however executing this gives `[: 1: !=: unexpected operator`. I've tried executing using -n but for whatever reason, even if the output is blank, using -n still runs the echo command.

Any help on this is appreciated. I've attached the code snippet below.

```
#!/bin/sh

HOST=$1
USER="/scripts/whoowns $HOST | tr -d '\r'"

ssh -t $HOST -p 22 -l deehem "sh -c 'if [ "" != "\`$USER\`" ]; then echo "Username for $HOST: \`$USER\`"; fi' ; bash -login"
```

Comment: Ah okay, worked out that it's because "" is blank. Is there any viable alternative to `"" != "$VAR"`?

Comment: SSH always starts a remote shell. Using `sh -c` inside it is redundant.

Comment: Rather than `[ "" != "$VAR" ]`, you can write `[ -n "$VAR" ]`.  Better yet, just do `test -n "$VAR"`. (ie, `if test -n "$VAR"; then ...`)

Answer (score 0):

As you realised, `"bla "" bla"` is just two strings concatenated (`"bla   bla"`).

You can escape the `"`: `\"`, but the standard `[` `test` tool has an option specifically for this task:

```
   -n STRING
          the length of STRING is nonzero

   -z STRING
          the length of STRING is zero
```

Note: why do you have \`? That way the string is never going to be empty....

Answer (score 0):

In regards to your "however executing this gives `[: 1: !=: unexpected operator`" problem, here is a solution:

Use `bash -c` instead of `sh -c`. The bash program seems to be better than sh at handling square brackets. For example:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/$ echo "antipetalous" | if [[ "antipetalous" =~ "ti" ]]; then echo "match"; else echo "no"; fi
match
ubuntu@ubuntu:/$ echo "antepetalous" | if [[ "antepetalous" =~ "ti" ]]; then echo "match"; else echo "no"; fi
no
ubuntu@ubuntu:/$ sh -c 'echo "antipetalous" | if [[ "antipetalous" =~ "ti" ]]; then echo "match"; else echo "no"; fi'
sh: 1: [[: not found
no
ubuntu@ubuntu:/$ bash -c 'echo "antipetalous" | if [[ "antipetalous" =~ "ti" ]]; then echo "match"; else echo "no"; fi'
match
ubuntu@ubuntu:/$ bash -c 'echo "antepetalous" | if [[ "antepetalous" =~ "ti" ]]; then echo "match"; else echo "no"; fi'
no
ubuntu@ubuntu:/$ sh -c 'echo "antepetalous" | if [[ "antepetalous" =~ "ti" ]]; then echo "match"; else echo "no"; fi'
sh: 1: [[: not found
no
ubuntu@ubuntu:/$
```

So `ssh -t $HOST -p 22 -l deehem "sh -c 'if [ "" != ...` would become `ssh -t $HOST -p 22 -l deehem "bash -c 'if [ "" != ...`.

Thanks to pLumo at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1310106/sh-c-sh-not-working-when-using-if-statement-and-having-in-the-filena ("command line - sh -c '...' sh {} not working when using if statement and having ' in the filename - Ask Ubuntu").

Comment: It's not a matter of "better than" -- `sh` only guarantees support for POSIX-standardized syntax, and `[[` is a standard-noncompliant extension.